# Providing a flag to NGINX Ingress Controller that doesn't run as a Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

In general, my question about setting up a default certificate is answered here: [Kubernetes ingress How to set default-ssl-certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972609/kubernetes-ingress-how-to-set-default-ssl-certificate).

What I don't understand is this part: I'm supposed to add the flag `--default-ssl-certificate=kube-system/host-cert` as the Ingress' argument. And to discover the YAML config file settings of the NGINX Ingress Controller I should check it with command like: `kubectl describe deployment/nginx-ingress-controller --namespace`. But it doesn't run as a deployment:

```
$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard         1/1     1            1           3d
kube-system   kubernetes-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           3d
```

It only works as a pod:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-8xcl9                1/1     Running   1 (2d ago)     3d
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-hwhvk                1/1     Running   1 (2d ago)     3d
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-xqdqx                1/1     Running   3 (2d ago)     3d
kube-system     kubernetes-dashboard-548847967d-66dwz         1/1     Running   2 (2d ago)     3d
kube-system     kubernetes-metrics-scraper-6d49f96c97-r6dz2   1/1     Running   1 (2d ago)     3d
[...]
```

How should I supply the flag to the Controller then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ingress-nginx` can be installed as deployment or daemonset. In your case if you don't see a deployment, it's a daemonset.

You can find it by running:

```
kubectl get daemonset -A
```

And edit in the same way as deployment:

```
kubectl edit daemonset ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
```

You can find details [here about ingress-nginx and daemonset](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network)

---

Note! Change you're going to make won't be permanent (until any upgrade/re-applying of manifest). Depending on how it was originally deployed, there are two options:

- from **manifest**

  you will need to add it to manifest so any other updates/`kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml` will contain this flags and everything will continue working
- using **helm**

  you will need to add this information to `helm_repo/templates/controller-daemonset.yaml`:

  ```
  args:
    - /nginx-ingress-controller
    ...
    - --default-ssl-certificate=kube-system/host-cert
    ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I applied the flag temporarily by editing the daemonset configuration, but I don't see any effects - the app still reports it's run without HTTPS. `describe` gave an output containing the argument with certificate, but should I maybe restart the daemonset or any other service to see any effects?

Comment: Hard to guess about other stuff without details, please consider asking [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) with ingress object manifest, certificate details and other helpful information. This is something you should start with: checking ingress rules if it's correct, check certificate, everything.